# Python KeyError when creating a Series for Matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I am graphing data that is stored in a csv.  I pull pull 2 columns of data into a dataframe then convert to series and graph with matplotlib.

```
 from pandas import Series
 from matplotlib import pyplot
 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
 import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('Proxy/Proxy_Analytics/API_Statistics.csv')

df
    Date        Distinct_FLD    Not_On_MM   API_Call_Count  Cost     CACHE_Count
0   2018-11-12  35711           18468       18468           8.31060  35711
1   2018-11-13  36118           18741       11004           4.95180  46715
2   2018-11-14  34073           17629       8668            3.90060  55383
3   2018-11-15  34126           17522       7817            3.51765  63200

#Cost
cost_df = df[['Date','Cost']]
cost_series = cost_df.set_index('Date')['Cost']

plt.style.use('dark_background')
plt.title('Domain Rank API Cost Over Time')
plt.ylabel('Cost in Dollars')
cost_series.plot(c = 'red')
plt.show()
```

And this works totally fine.  I would like to do the same and graph multiple rows but when I try to convert the df to series I am getting an error:

```
#Not Cost
not_cost = df[['Date','Distinct_FLD','Not_On_MM','API_Call_Count','CACHE_Count']]
not_cost_series = not_cost.set_index('Date')['Distinct_FLD','Not_On_MM','API_Call_Count','CACHE_Count']
```

Error:

```
KeyError: ('Distinct_FLD', 'Not_On_MM', 'API_Call_Count', 'CACHE_Count')
```

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: Why did you use `(...)` instead of `[...]` on the line that is erroring out?

Comment: Im sorry I had it like [...] then I started playing with the code to try to get it to work, and that was the last thing I tried and ended up copying that over.  I will fix that.

Comment: pandas is looking for a column ('Distinct_FLD', 'Not_On_MM', 'API_Call_Count', 'CACHE_Count'), use not_cost.set_index('Date')[['Distinct_FLD','Not_On_MM','API_Call_Count','CACHE_Count']] to pass multiple columns

Comment: seems like "close as typo"?

Comment: You have a typo, add `[` and `]` wrapping your list

Comment: I added the extra []  but it is still a dataframe.  I am looking to convert to a Series.  
    type(not_cost_series)
    pandas.core.frame.DataFrame

Comment: Why do you need a series vs a dataframe, plot will plot each column(pd.Series) in your dataframe wrt the dataframe index?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you are trying to convert the columns of a DataFrame into multiple Series, indexed by the 'Date' column of your DataFrame.

Maybe you can try:

```
not_cost = df[['Date','Distinct_FLD','Not_On_MM','API_Call_Count','CACHE_Count']]

not_cost_series = not_cost.set_index('Date')

Distinct_FLD    = not_cost_series['Distinct_FLD']
Not_On_MM       = not_cost_series['Not_On_MM'] 

.
.
.
```